# Not able to import UserNotifications in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, usernotifications

I'm trying to implement push notification by using Firebase. I have installed the 'Firebase/Core' and 'Firebase/Messaging' frameworks using cocapod.
 I'm able to import FirebaseInstanceID & FirebaseMessaging in the File. But for **"import UserNotifications"** it says **"No Such Module"**. I'm using **Swift 2.1.1** and **Xcode 7.3.1** and my targeted iOS is 8.1+ ...
Kindly Help, thanks in advance .

Comment: This class is not available in `Xcode 7.3.1`. Use the `xcode 8`.

Comment: the UserNotifications is only available from iOS 10+ -- you need Xcode 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications) is available from iOS 10 and later.
Xcode 7.3.1 support upto iOS 9 only.
If you need to use this framework. You need to update to latest Xcode(obviously Xcode8) which supports iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to XCode 8 is probably the best option.

But if you can't or don't want to upgrade for some reason you can use old way of APN Registration (without importing UserNotifications):

```
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Firebase Messaging will work, but some new iOS10 features might not function.